# Cредства для выражения незаконченности действия в данный момент

Tags: грамотная-речь

У меня внуки в гостях. Играют в нечто, навеянное сказками, слышу что-то о князьях и княгинях. И вдруг: "Я тебе отрубляю голову". Понимаю, что неправильно. Варю суп и мысленно исправляю: "рублю".  Но рублю и "отрубляю" - не одно и то же. Рублю - еще не значит "отрублю", а вот отрубляю - это еще рублю, действие не закончено, но обязательно будет доведено до конца (мне кажется, именно такое значение придает приставка "от", хотя, может, я и не права).

Вопрос: есть ли в русском языке грамматические средства для выражения незаконченности действия в данный момент, но обязательной его совершенности в будущем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чем плохо в данной ситуации "я тебе отрубаю голову"? По-моему, по контексту имелось в виду именно это. Или же "я тебе рублю голову" — тоже вариант.

Comment: Ну конечно же. Совсем мне голову детки, видать, за две недели заморочили -  явного не вижу. Спасибо. Удалите, вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ни в коем случае! Вопрос хороший, пусть будет!

Answer (score 3):

> А чем плохо в данной ситуации "я тебе отрубаю голову"?

Всем хорошо, только не соответствует поставленным условиям.

[[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f), грамматических средств, которые в точности бы соответствовали подобным требованиям, в русском, разумеется, нет. Лексических и, так сказать, морфо-семантических - сколько угодно. "Я отрубаю - и отрублю" - вот именно это значение Вы фактически требуете своей формулировкой.

Несовершенный вид в русском отнюдь не означает неизбежности совершения действия в будущем. Сравните - "я отрубал" - не значит, что отрубил. Вообще в русской грамматике глагола есть какая-то лакуна в описании видовой пары... Несовершенный вид говорит о том, что действие происходит (происходило, будет происходить) в какой-то обозначенный момент времени, но ничего не говорит о результате. Напротив, совершенный вид (в некотором отличие от европейского имперфекта) показывает, что действие не просто завершилось, но и завершилось результативно, т.е. цель действия достигнута. Для всех промежуточных ситуаций приходится изобретать нечто типа "недорубил".

А вообще я очень сомневаюсь, что в каком-то языке может существовать подобная грамматика. Даже не знаю, как её могли бы назвать, чтобы хоть знать, на что искать. Какой-то особый тип причастного аблатива, что ли...

Comment: Рассмотрите, пожалуйста, на системе времен английского языка. Мне кажется, что вполне подходит.

Comment: Не вижу ничего подходящего. В английском, как и в русском, два вида - перфект и имперфект. Имперфект отбрасываем сразу, остаётся перфект, обычный и продолженный. Первый при всем многообразии значений смысла "незаконченности" нести, насколько понимаю, не может. Второй, по моему глубокому, форма абсолютно искусственная, не жизненная, используемая реально только в значении "как давно [это делаете]?". Конечно, какой-то смысл незаконченности во фразе типа "How long have you been working on this project?" существует, но зато у неё нет перфектной завершенности...